# Dirichlet function

Tags: calculus

I thought maybe there is any connection to that "one" in the numerator :

$$ \text{let }  f(x):[-2,2]→(0,∞)\quad \text{be a continuous function for every } x  $$
$$\text{Prove that}\quad f(x)=D(x)\quad\text{ has  a solution in the  section }  [-2,2]  $$

$$f(x+\sqrt{2})=\frac{1}{f(x)}$$
$$D(x)= \text{Dirichlet  function}$$

On the one hand, I can say that $f(x)$ is continuous,  the "image" can get any value and in particular for non-$\Bbb Q$ numbers → Dirichlet function gets a  value of 1 and I finish. I have a feeling this is not the way to solve it and there is a meaning to the limits they gave in the question.
I am incompetent. If anyone can help me, I will appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Since $1$ is between $t$ and $1/t$ for any positive number $t$, by the intermediate value theorem, $f(x)=1$ for some $x\in[0,\sqrt 2]$. If $x$ is irrational, then we're done. Otherwise, $x-\sqrt 2$ is in $[-2,2]$ and is irrational.

Comment: can you pls explain how and why you took x−2–√ rather than "+" ?

Comment: Because we cannot guarantee that $x+\sqrt 2$ is in $[-2,2]$

Comment: ok, so can we choose to take "negative" althought the function defined with "+" ?

Comment: Substituting $x$ with $x-\sqrt 2$ in the given condition shows that $f(x) = 1/f(x-\sqrt 2) $, so if $f(x) =1$, then $f(x-\sqrt 2)=1$.

Comment: i think now my answer gonna be perfect thanks to you!! this is for my final task so i wanted to be sure i explain every step. thank you verry much !!